# How to import Excel (both 2003 and 2007 version) files in to MySQL using Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I have requirement to import Excel file in MySQL database using Java.  I Googled it and got the answer is to export CSV files from Excel then import it using`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'SampleData.csv' INTO TABLE databasetable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`.  It works nicely.

I have doubts why we convert Excel files to CSV then import file into an database. Is there is another technique to import Excel without converting into CSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is a plaintext file format showing the contents of the Excel file as *Comma Separated Values* (CSV)

This is done so that the Java program need not know how to parse the Excel Files themselves, which is a big bonus.

Consider the recent change that Office underwent with the Office 2007 release. Their new file format `.xlsx` was not backwards compatible with their former `.xls` format. This is because the `.xlsx` format compressed the contents.

If your program parsed the `.xls` files directly, it would have broken during this changeover. With the CSV conversion, you should be able to read any new Excel format for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 3):

Try Apache POI.

http://poi.apache.org/

More info on why POI is possibly better than JExcel and other alternatives:

[Which is better open source for Excel file parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740060/which-is-better-open-source-for-excel-file-parsing-in-java)

Comment: thanks for quick reply but i have different question "why we need to convert excel file into csv before import it into database?"

Comment: See Peaches491's answer.

However, in case you were saying I was answering the wrong question, from your original question: _"Is there is another technique to import excel without converting into csv."_ That is what I answered.